# Environment Variable for Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: cordova, android-studio, environment-variables, ionic3, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to build my android project with Ionic by the following command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I read a lot of threads about setting the ANDROID_HOME env variable to mac os. I've edited the .bash_profile and right now it looks like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=Users/christiangehn/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

But still I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):


Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting 
setting it manually.

Detected 'adb' command at /usr/local/Cellar/android-platform-tools/24/bin 
but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.

Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to 
SDK/platform-tools directory.
```

I've checked env variable by printenv at the terminal.

```
ANDROID_HOME=Users/christiangehn/Library/Android/sdk

PATH=Users/christiangehn/Library/Android/sdk/
tools:Users/christiangehn/Library/Android/sdk/
platform-tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Can you guys please take a look at what I've done and tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem

There had been some relicts of an older android SDK version at this mac. Ionic never tried to look up for my configured variables because it always tried to use the adb file as written inside the error message.

```
Detected 'adb' command at /usr/local/Cellar/android-platform-tools/24/bin 
but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.
```

After deleting this file Ionic recognized the env variable.

Comment: I dont get an error message. I have adb, but it is not set via the environment variable, even though I double checked whether it is set correctly.